# Possible to create registration system with sqlite and python?

Tags: python, sqlite, pyqt

I have created a login system using python, pyqt and SQLite however I am wondering whether it is possible to create a registration system. At the moment I store the usernames and passwords in a SQLite database by myself inputting them in and you are able to login with these usernames and passwords. However I want the user to be able to make their own username and password by entering their username and password into a QLineEdit, then click a register button and the system to automatically store these in a database.

This is my code:

```
import sys
from PyQt4.Qt import *
import sys
from PyQt4 import QtGui, QtCore
import sqlite3
conn = sqlite3.connect('login.db')

cursor = conn.execute("SELECT count(*) FROM sqlite_master WHERE type='table' AND name='STUDENT';")
if cursor.fetchone()[0] == 0:
  conn.execute('''CREATE TABLE STUDENT
       (FORENAME           TEXT    NOT NULL,
       SURNAME            TEXT     NOT NULL,
       USERNAME           TEXT   PRIMARY KEY,
       PASSWORD         TEXT);''')


  conn.execute("INSERT INTO STUDENT (FORENAME,SURNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD) \
      VALUES ('Sean', 'Ryan', 'sryan', 'hello' )");

  conn.execute("INSERT INTO STUDENT (FORENAME,SURNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD) \
      VALUES ('Jeff', 'Smith', 'jsmith', 'database' )");

  conn.execute("INSERT INTO STUDENT (FORENAME,SURNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD) \
      VALUES ('Teddy', 'Brown', 'tbrown', 'football' )");

  conn.execute("INSERT INTO STUDENT (FORENAME,SURNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD) \
      VALUES ('Mark', 'Thompson', 'mthompson', 'computer' )");

  conn.execute("INSERT INTO STUDENT (FORENAME,SURNAME,USERNAME,PASSWORD) \
      VALUES ('John', 'Brown', 'jbrown', 'phone' )");

  conn.commit()

class Login(QtGui.QDialog):
    def __init__(self):
        QtGui.QDialog.__init__(self)
        self.textName = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.textName.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.textName.setPlaceholderText("Username");
        self.textPass = QtGui.QLineEdit(self)
        self.textPass.setEchoMode(self.textPass.Password)
        self.textPass.setFixedWidth(150)
        self.textPass.move(200,100)
        self.textPass.setPlaceholderText("Password");
        self.buttonLogin = QtGui.QPushButton('Login', self)
        self.buttonLogin.clicked.connect(self.handleLogin)
        layout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout(self)
        layout.addWidget(self.textName)
        layout.addWidget(self.textPass)
        layout.addWidget(self.buttonLogin)
        self.buttonLogin.setFixedWidth(100)

        self.setGeometry(700,300,200,200)
        self.setWindowTitle("Login")



    def handleLogin(self):
      cursor = conn.execute("SELECT count(*)  from STUDENT where USERNAME = '" + str(self.textName.text()) + "' and PASSWORD = '" + str(self.textPass.text()) + "'")
      if cursor.fetchone()[0] == 0:
          QtGui.QMessageBox.warning(
              self, 'Error', 'Incorrect username or password')
      else:
          self.accept()
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use python-social-auth for this with the email backend.
See the [docs](https://github.com/omab/python-social-auth/blob/master/docs/backends/email.rst) here for details.

I use python-social-auth with Google+ and Facebook auth, but the email backend allows you to have traditional username/password registration, with you storing the password and username.

Personally, I've gone for using third party auth such as G+ and Facebook. Not everyone's cup to tea though.

Python-social-auth is my favourite. You might also consider django-allauth, or if you really just want something pretty simple try django-registration.